# SQL YEAR(GETDATE())

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, variables

I'm currently working on a query that returns records from within a date range. The ideal is for the start date to be everything from 2015 onward. In theory, shouldn't each of the three SET statements below set the variable to 2015*?

```
DECLARE @startDate datetime;
SET @startDate = '20150101';
SET @startDate = YEAR(GETDATE());
SET @startDate = DATEPART(yyyy,GETDATE());
```

Only the first one, the hardcoded date, behaves as expected. The other two return ALL records that are being queried through. Am I missing something here?

*EDIT: I apologize for how unclear I was with that initially. Basically, `@startDate` should be set to 01-01-XXXX, where XXXX is whatever year today's date is a part of. It's being compared against another `DATETIME` variable. I hope that clarifies things.

Comment: How these values are used in `where` clause, can you add the query. Second an third `@startDate` will have this date `1905-07-09 00:00:00.000`

Comment: You should have an index on the table's date column and then use a date so it can use that index.  So WHERE myDate >= '1/1/2015'

Comment: `WHERE ([Date Requested]) >= (@startDate) `

Comment: @NoDisplayName, Why would they return that particular date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is "No".  The variable `@StartDate` is date time.  This doesn't make sense:

```
set @startDate = 2015
```

It doesn't make sense.  An integer that looks like a year is not a date.

If you want the first day of the year, you can do:

```
set @startDate = dateadd(day,
                         1 - datepart(dayofyear, getdate()),
                         cast(getdate() as date)
                         ) as FirstDayOfYear
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this would work (for SQL-Server):

```
SET @startDate = cast(YEAR(GETDATE()) as varchar(4))
SET @startDate = cast(DATEPART(yyyy,GETDATE()) as varchar(4))
```

This will show you what's happening:

```
DECLARE @startDate datetime
SET @startDate = '20150101'
select @startdate
SET @startDate = YEAR(GETDATE()) 
select @startdate
SET @startDate = cast(YEAR(GETDATE()) as varchar(4))
select @startdate
SET @startDate = DATEPART(yyyy,GETDATE()) 
select @startdate
SET @startDate = cast(DATEPART(yyyy,GETDATE()) as varchar(4))
select @startdate
```

Answer (score 0):

`YEAR(GETDATE())` and `DATEPART(yyyy,GETDATE());` will return *just the year part* of the date, so if you ran them today you would get `2015` back, not the *date* `2015-01-01` as you seem to want.

If you want to force the date value to the beginning of the current year, one way would be:

```
SET @startDate = YEAR(GETDATE()) + '-01-01';
```

Comment: `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

Comment: That should have been `SET @startDate = STR(YEAR(GETDATE()),4) + '-01-01';`