# SQL Report Builder Error: Argument not specified for parameter 'DateValue' of 'Public Function Day(DateValue As Date) As Integer'

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I'm quite new to Report Builder, and looking to apply the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28095314/sql-yeargetdate/28095645) to a report I'm working on. I have `@startDate` established as a Parameter, but trying to set its value to `= dateadd(day, 1 - datepart(dayofyear, getdate()), cast(getdate() as date));` gives me this error.

> The Value expression for the report parameter ‘startDate’ contains an error: [BC30455] Argument not specified for parameter 'DateValue' of 'Public Function Day(DateValue As Date) As Integer'.

Now, I can set the Default Value of `@startDate` to `=Today()` and it works fine...except for the fact I can't change the date *from* that in the report itself, without establishing some Available Values. However, whether the above expression is set to Available or Default Values, the report crashes with that error message.

I would like to keep `=Today()` as the Default Value, with the above expression as one of the Available Values. Can anyone explain to me what I may be doing wrong, and the most sensible solution to it?

Comment: Where are you setting the default value? In Report Builder Parameter options or in the SQL Query?

Answer (score 0):

Try set this as your default value within Report Builder itself, Parameter properties - Default Value - fx:

```
=DateValue(CStr(Year(Today())) + "-01-01")
```